# CSS height transition on DOM element removal

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Is there a pure CSS way of applying a height transition animation to a DIV element when one of the child elements of this DIV is removed from DOM?

Example code:

```
<div id="master">
  <div id="child1">
     some content
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
     some other content
  </div>
</div>
```

If `child1` element is removed the height of `master` element is adjusted automatically. How to apply transition animation to it?
Traditional `transition:height` does not seem to work.

Comment: When _one of the_ child elements? No.  When _the last child element_ is? Probably (`div:empty`).  How is the element removed?  If you're removing with javascript, you might be able to do something to trigger the css transition.

Comment: You will not be able to use transition on ANY property unless its specifically set in your CSS.

This is something you are going to want to use JS for. I'd recommend using the jQuery .slideUp() function and then removing the element once the slideUp animation is finished.